# WPF dependency property - Get ignored

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following class:

```
public class Person:DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(String), typeof(Person));

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                string result = (string)GetValue(NameProperty);
                return result;
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(NameProperty, value);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the following Window:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingSelf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind for Window is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Person p = null;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            p = new Person();
            p.Name = "Test1";
            this.DataContext = p;
        }

    }
```

TextBox is bound to Name and it's value ("Test1") correctly shows when I run the application. Now here's my question, if I set a break point in the Get part of the Name property it is completely ignored. I've done a few tests and even If I return empty "Test1" still shows, could somebody explain what's happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) link is self explanatory:

> The current WPF implementation of its XAML processor is inherently
>   dependency property aware. The WPF *XAML processor uses property system
>   methods for dependency properties when loading binary XAML and
>   processing attributes that are dependency properties*. This effectively
>   **bypasses the property wrappers**. When you implement custom dependency
>   properties, you must account for this behavior and should avoid
>   placing any other code in your property wrapper other than the
>   property system methods GetValue and SetValue.